# Why Fantom compiler complains about a class that has a Func field?

Tags: fantom

I wrote a Fantom script that defines a bunch of classes. As I could run the script successfully, I decided to convert this into a proper Fantom project, but one of the classes cannot be compiled and the error message is:

```
Expected expression, not '|'
```

The class has this form:

```
class MyClass
{
    const Func myFunc := |Foo foo, Bar bar| {
        // do stuff
    }

    MyType myVar := MyType()

    Void main() {
        // do more stuff
    }

}
```

I don't understand why the compiler complains when this class is part of a Fantom project, but doesn't if is part of a Fantom script instead. Can anyone shed some light, please?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a just a bad error message on Fantom's behalf. It is actually complaining that the classes `Foo` and `Bar` don't exist. Add the following to your project and all should compile okay.

```
class Foo {}
class Bar {}
class MyType {}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Steve. You are very right! It is a bad error message. The Foo class actually exists next to MyClass, but the Bar class belongs to another pod for which I missed the "using" statement.